# How to get Google Review by display name

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-my-business-api

I want to check if someone reviewed my business with its name. The user enters his google name and then I send a get request to check if the review exists. In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data) it says I can get a review with this url

```
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/account_name/locations/location_name/reviews/review_name
```

I suppose `accont_name` and `location_name` are related to my My Business Account and I can find them somewhere there.

But what exactly is `review_name`? Is it the name of the Google Account who wrote the review? If yes what happens when two different Google Accounts with the same Name write a Review? Do I get two reviews back then? How can I tell which review is related to which account?

Answer (score 0):

Review name is not the name of Google Account which has written the review, it means the 'reviewId' field that you get from the list of reviews. You have to pass it like below:

```
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{account_name}/locations/{location_name}/reviews/{reviewId}
```

It will return to you the single review object.